# ASP.NET Core Identity user groups

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, relational-database, entity-relationship

Hi I'm planning a website where each user should be able to create groups and then invite other users to join the group. So what I'm planning to do is a many-to-many realtion ship betwen the identityUser and a group-table. Is this a good idea or are their other to achive this in a better way?

Comment: To keep it consistent with the format of ASP.NET Identity, I'd have a Groups table (similar to AspNetRoles) and then have a UserGroups table (similar to AspNetUserRoles) but this just opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an *intermediary* table in your database design.

This would lead to three tables:

- Users
- Groups
- UserGroups

UserGroups would contain the primary keys from the Users and Groups tables.